# In blockchain every node have the separate copy of blocks data. if my machine not having that much space then how it works?

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum

I am new to use stackoverflow and and also new to learn about blockchain. I alleady read about blockchain in which they told in blockchain every node have the copy of blocks. But i cant understand one thing if my machine don't have enough space to store all block records. Then how i can access the history and maintain the all block data on my machine. or am i accessing this data from somewhere. 
             And how they authenticate the valid user to check history. and where this history stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume the data will fit in memory.

What you can do is use a database, or write a custom store using memory mapped files so you can access all the data on your disk.

Comment: Is that mean i need my own storage for storing new blocks data and block history. Is it mandatory to have big data storage for connecting in blockchain as a node?

Comment: @KrishnaMane If you want to validate transactions, you need to have access to every block in an efficient manner.

Comment: Thank you but still i am in confusion my doubt is if i want to connect with blockchain(i want to do some transaction), then what is hardware requirement( eg RAM, HARDDISK, Processor).

Comment: @KrishnaMane your knowledge of blockchain is extremely limited. It is recommended you google and study basic stuff from a few resources, take bitcoin for starters. A clear understanding of few basic concepts will answer most of your questions.

Comment: @KrishnaMane if you want to connect to a blockchain I suggest you use a client API to an existing service rather than run a node yourself. This will require only the client library installed.